# Hline and Cline in multirow/multicolumn environment

Tags: tables

Why when I using  using multirow and multicolumn, my horizontal line does not appear?
This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\multirow{2}{*}{Iterasi} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ Ketinggian rata-rata (\%)}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Luas Sebaran (\%)} \\ 
\cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test}
\label{tabel  stiffness}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `\multicolumn` you cannot stop a `\cline` at a column that is 'inside' of the `\multicolumn`, so changing `\cline{2-6}` to be `\cline{2-7}` in your code works.

Also, if you want to use `\multirow`, you actually need to include another row, otherwise you won't get "Iterasi" to be in two rows.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\multirow{2}{*}{Iterasi} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Ketinggian rata-rata (\%)}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Luas Sebaran (\%)} \\ \cline{2-7}
\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Test}
\label{tabel  stiffness}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]